# When did Martin Scorsese say "the most personal is the most creative"?

Tags: reference, martin-scorsese

In his acceptance speech for the Academy Award for Best Director, Bong Joon-Ho - director of *Parasite* - famously said that "the most personal [filmmaking] is the most creative" and said that he was quoting Martin Scorsese. However, I looked up and I can't find what Scorsese's exact quote was/when he said it. Can anyone point me to it?

Comment: After some googling, this quote (and variations) only appears to have hit the internet AFTER Joon-Ho's Oscar speech.  I think it is most likely that either this was: a) something Scorsese said to him personally off the record, or that b) Scorsese inspired him early in his career and he constructed this as a mantra to remind him how Scorsese inspired him.

Comment: Here is a stab at the source quote "It was, from the start, to create highly personal and impressionistic films as seen through the eyes of the most creative directors around with a passion for this music."  It was in regards to the Blues film series on PBS in 2003. https://www.pbs.org/theblues/aboutfilms/aboutfilms.html

Answer (score -1):

It was not translated in English by the translator, but Bong said he got this quote from a book. I am a native Korean and just re-watched his speech.

Comment: Did he say what the book was called, or who wrote it?